# Selenium driver StackOverflowException

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

When I create webdriver this way

```
  val mobileEmulation = Map("deviceName" -> "Google Nexus 5")
  val chromeOptions = Map("mobileEmulation" -> mobileEmulation)
  val capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome()
  capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions)

  new ChromeDriver(capabilities)
```

I have `java.lang.StackOverflowException` with lots of lines `at org.openqa.selenium.remote.BeanToJsonConverter.convertObject(BeanToJsonConverter.java:205)`

Does somebody know why this might happen?

Comment: Can you share the top few lines of the exception? Those are usually the most relevant. Also, is this a single instance? Or are you running a bunch of drivers in parallel? Or collecting them without cleaning them up?

Comment: ```java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.lang.Class.searchMethods(Class.java:3003)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)

```

Comment: I tried both creating single and several drivers but got the same error

Comment: What I noticed is that actually method newInstance() was invoked twice and after that program fails. Without such capabilities all works fine and newInstance() is invoked ones.

Comment: method `newInstance` returns new driver for lazy val driver

Comment: Sounds like you may have figured it out? If you show the entire method and how you're calling it that might help. Possibly a recursive call with no exit. It also would probably help if you posted the entire stack trace in the question, it seems like there is some important information missing there.

Comment: It was stupid mistake, I shouldn't pass scala's Map collection to setCapabilities method but java.util.HashMap...